# yii framework's CRUD generator (gii) shows error message : "'Voucher' must extend from CActiveRecord."

Tags: php, crud, yii, gii

I am trying to generate CRUD for my vouchers table using gii,I follow simple steps through which I always generate CRUD but this time with "vouchers" tables its showing some unexpected error message

> 'Voucher' must extend from CActiveRecord.

Below is how I am trying to generate the CRUD.

**Step 1: Model Generation:**

[image: Model Generation]

Her is generated voucher model located in root/protected/models/Voucher.php

[image: Voucher.php]

**Step 2: CRUD Generation:**

[image: CRUD generation]

**Workaround:**

I tried to generate CRUD with path alias for model class and it works, have a look at screen below

[image: workaround]

About workaround solved the problem but I wonder why CRUD generator is not generating the CRUD as normally it does with all other model names. I noticed that it shows this error only for "Voucher" model and for this specific model I have to go for above workaround.

Comment: do you have any other voucher class?

Comment: @bool.dev yes I noticed that there was a component named 'Voucher'. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that there is a class named 'Voucher' in root/protected/components/ folder that is causing above problem. Renamed it and issue resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that same name in class name due to anothe error too.I prefer avoiding create Class with the same name in yii.